# Openssh Connection refused when AuthorizedKeysCommand is present

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ldap, openssh, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to authenticate a user in LDAP using ssh key pairs. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.
I have LDAP setup with a user account that has an ssh public key objectclass (already applied schema). However there is supposably a new command that openssh sshd_config is able to accept called AuthorizedKeysCommand which accepts a script to lookup ssh keys for a user.

See [combine_ssh_public-key_and_ldap_on_ubuntu](https://marc.waeckerlin.org/computer/index#combine_ssh_public-key_and_ldap_on_ubuntu)

My problem is that when I add this command and then restart sshd, it does not listen on port 22. It says

```
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running
```

And when I run 'service ssh status', I see this:

```
ssh start/running
```

However, when I try to connect, ie. 'ssh localhost', I get this:

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

When I check the listening ports with

```
netstat -a | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'
```

I see this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 10.5.0.36:domain        *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:953           *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ldap                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:953       [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ldap               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

So ssh is not listening on port 22, it's not listening on any port. It doesn't even look like it started. 
When I comment out this one line in my sshd_conf it starts fine.

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand "/etc/ssh/ldap-keys.sh"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

ssh -V returns 1:6.6p1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the reason this was not working was because I was not supplying AuthorizedKeysCommandUser in sshd_config.

This was advertised as an optional addition, however it seems that in my case it was required. I just added

AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root

Comment: I have exactly same problem (even the SO) but AuthorizedKeysCommandUser don't fix it.
I have set LogLevel to DEBUG but sshd writes nothing at all in log

Could you post your script and file permissions?

Comment: Could you post your sshd_config too?

Comment: Sorry I no longer have access to it, and I don't think I'd be allowed to post it anyways.
Consider changing the order of AuthorizedKeysCommandUser, and make sure the user is after it (in my case root).

Comment: It appears that versions of openssh < 6.9 have limited options for the AuthorizedKeysCommand and so if you malform the configuration, it may show running (existing user remained logged in) but it is not accepting connections (e.g. nothing listening on 0.0.0.0:22).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the exact same issue, but I'm wary of running anything as root, so I added:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

And that fixed the problem as well.

Comment: This makes AuthorizedKeysCommand unusable when it needs to read user files with no permission to read by others.